# How to get item to appear on mobile homepage only(wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I asked a question the other day on here regarding getting a category on my mobile homepage. I was given this code, and it worked:

```
<?php
// Feed PHP with the information you want to show, in our case: a certain category = use of the id, number = amount of posts to show
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=1' );
// Let WordPress run the loop for you
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<!--Inside the loop, you can use the WP template tags to show the stuff you         want, like author, exerpt of the post etc. -->
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php // Don't forget to reset the query (clean the data after it is     finished) ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I currently have it set via custom css to only show up on mobile, but I am trying to figure out how to get the item to only display on the mobile homepage, not subsequent pages.

Thanks!! Your help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to hide it on devices bigger than mobile.

To stop this code getting executed on every page wrap it into a if_front_page().
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    // your code only on front page
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want! I tried wrapping the above php statement in that if statement and it did not work, it just printed the if statement on the page. Where should I be placing this?

Comment: in the template you want.. index.php in your themes folder for example.. or page.php if if your frontpage is a page.

Comment: That's what I thought. I did that and it just prints out the if statement. here is what it looks like: http://pastebin.com/LU2jU7ra

Comment: This code was correct! My error is something with my slider, which has the same image on it right now, so I was assuming it was my code messing it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Write your css for elements to appear in mobile

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
/* you css for element*/
}
```

Comment: I thought I had included that I had done this in CSS already, sorry, I edited my post. I just need to know how to get it on homepage only, not on EVERY mobile page. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Unless you heavily modified your theme, the body of the homepage should have a class just called "home". You can use that as a top-level selector for anything within your mobile query. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress automatically adds a class of `home` to your body tag if you are on the homepage.

Set the CSS controlling that code to `display: none;` generally and do `.home *element class or id* { display: block;}`

Answer (score 0):

wordpress has a built-in is_mobile function.

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ) {
      /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
}
```

Comment: I wrapped my code in this, but it's still appearing on the top of the second page, cut off.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs in to this, it's easier to just move your php code to a separate php file and include it in your index - like this:

`<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
<?php include ('News.php'); ?>
<?php endif ?>`